# DistributedMap and infinispan

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I'm not familiar with IBM products but I'm considering to give IBM Bluemix a try. Previously I have experiences with Red Hat JBoss products. I like IBoss EAP 6 and Infinispan combination. Basically, when I have 2 JBoss EAP 6 running on 2 different machines, I can have them share common cache via infinispan. So now, when I try IBM Bluemix, I disconver that I can have similiar functionality with distributedMap. My questions are:

1. When 2 Liberty instances are running (cloud foundry), can they share
   the same cache with distributedMap? I ask so because I'm afraid it
   can't be achieved on the cloud.
2. If I have 3 instances of Liberty running, can I have my data be
   cached in shared mode like; 1/3 of the cache data is saved on
   instance one, 1/3 of my data is saved on instance 2 and the rest of
   data is cached on instance 3? I don't want the cached data to be
   replicated on all 3 instances. This can be done trivially with JBoss
   and Infinispan. I just don't know whether it can be done with
   Liberty on IBM Blue Mix and distributedMap.

Comment: I see that you didn't mention "extreme scale". As I understand it, it's what puts the distributed in distributed map (and an alternative to RDBMS for  session persistence) on Liberty. It's sometimes abbreviated WXS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm considering Liberty on IBM Bluemix even though my app is running well on OpenShift. The reason is the premium plans of it are only available in some countries and my country is not in the list, so I can't scale my app if I need more resources.

Comment: anyway, your suggestion doesn't answer my questions.